# Создать список или массив веб-элементов

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

Столкнулся с такой задачей которую не выходит решить.
Нужно проверить на одинаковость два списка веб-элементов которые отображаются после нажатия кнопки сайта.
Решил что стоит найти кнопку по локатору, кликнуть и создать список веб элементов. Но столкнулся с проблемой как сделать тот самый список ? Нужно добавлять по одному элементу или можно как то сразу последовательность элементов закинуть?

[image: Сайт yandex.ru]

Нужно как то переместить все эти элементы в список. Есть ли возможность сделать это сразу как будто циклом ? Или нужно будет искать на каждый элемент локатор ?

Думаю добавлять по одному элементу не самый лучший вариант

```
 ChromeDriver ChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>();
        
        public void AddElements()
        {
            elements.Add(ChromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='services-new__icon'][1]")));
        }
```

Comment: Покажите код, вашу попытку решить задачу.

Comment: @aepot Код я писал только на каждый элемент отдельно и добавлял в список. Вопрос можно ли как то сразу все элементы. То есть что бы как цикл шел по нужным элементам и добавлял их в список.

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Был ли полезен мой ответ? Если да, отметьте его принятым.

Comment: @aepot К сожалению пока нет, на данный момент искал каждый элемент по отдельности. Но буду пробовать решать по другому потом, пока сделаю все что нужно по задаю, потом рефакторинг и там уже отпишусь.

Comment: Так в чем собственно проблема то? Код, который я показал ниже, не работает?

Comment: @aepot Все вроде началось решатся! Код помог спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из того что я вижу в [API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/Methods_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver.htm), я бы как-то так написал.

```cs
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
List<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".services-new__icon")).ToList();
```